# Green's function for the Laplace or Helmholtz equations for an open rectangle in 2d or cylinder 3d?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian, greens-function, spherical-harmonics

I have only ever worked with free space Green's functions, or Green's functions for for the upper half space in 2d.

So is it possible to determine a Green's function for the Helmholtz equation or Laplace equations for an open rectangle in 2d or an open cylinder or in 3d?

By open I mean that one end of the rectangle or cylinder is "missing".

Comment: Do you mean a rectangle that is unbounded in one direction, such as $\{(x,y) | 0 \le x < \infty, 0 \le y \le 1\}$?

Comment: If you have the fundamental solution for free space, then you can add a solution of the homogeneous equation so that the sum of the free space Green function and the homogeneous solution match the required boundary conditions. Courant-Hilbert deals with topics of that sort.